# Найти минимальный элемент массива среди элементов, расположенных в нечетных строках массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть задача которую я не могу решить, вопрос в том как её вообще решить то? Пробовал всё с одномерным массивом и всё работает, но вот не знаю как сделать с двумерным массивом

**Дан массив А (7, 7). Нужно найти минимальный элемент среди элементов, расположенных в нечетных строках массива**

```
$arr =array(range(3,25), range(3,25));
shuffle($arr);
$odd = array();
$even = array();
foreach ($arr as $val){
    if ($val%2==1){
        $odd[]=$val;
    }
    else{
        $even[]= $val;
    }
}
// Вывод самого массива ( с нечетными элементами )
echo '<pre>';
print_r($odd);
echo '</pre>';
// Вывод минимального элемента среди массива
$min = min($odd);
print_r($min); // Ответ 3
```

Хотел бы увидеть правильное решение данной задачи

Comment: рекомендую любой учебник. Там написано как работать с двумерными массивами.

Comment: у вас цикл по первому уровню массива. надо проверять индекс чтобы взять нужные строки, а вы берете саму строку $val - массив. и почему то делите его на 2. Вам нужен двойной цикл. первый по строка, второй по столбцам. В первом проверяете номер строки. Во втором ищите минимум

Answer (score 0):

маловероятно, что у вас примут такое решение,  так что вот:

```
$result = min(...array_filter($data, fn($v) => $v % 2, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```